# Como generar una tabla dinamica de excel con vb.net y openxml?

Tags: excel, vb.net, openxml

Tengo que generar un archivo de excel con dos libros, en uno debe tener información de un datable cargado desde la base de datos,(esta parte ya está hecha) y luego debo agregar otro libro que contenga una tabla dinamica usando de referencia la tabla agregada al primer libro, y aquí es donde tengo problemas.

A continuación dejo el código de como se genera el archivo de excel.

```
Dim FileName As String = NombreArchivo
Dim Destination As String = f.SelectedPath + "\" + FileName
Using document As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(Destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)
Dim workbookPart As WorkbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart()
workbookPart.Workbook = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook
Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
Dim sheetData = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData()
worksheetPart.Worksheet = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData)
Dim sheets As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets())
Dim sheet As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() With {
    .Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
    .SheetId = 1,
    .Name = "Sheet1"
}
sheets.Append(sheet)
Dim headerRow As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()
Dim columns As New List(Of String)()

For Each column As System.Data.DataColumn In table.Columns
    columns.Add(column.ColumnName)
    Dim cell As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell With {
         .DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String,
         .CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName)
    }
    headerRow.AppendChild(cell)
Next

sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow)
Dim rowINdex As Integer = 0
For Each dsrow As DataRow In table.Rows
    If CtrAvanceRpt1 Is Nothing = False Then
        If CtrAvanceRpt1.IncrementaVisual(rowINdex) = False Or Cancela_Reporte = True Then
            Return False
        End If
    End If
    rowINdex += 1
    Dim newRow As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()

    For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
        Dim cell As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
        Dim valor As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue
            If col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double") Then
               If IsDBNull(dsrow(col.ColumnName)) Then
                    dsrow(col.ColumnName) = 0
               End If
               cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number
               valor = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(CDbl(dsrow(col.ColumnName)))
            ElseIf col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32") Or col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int16") Or col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.UInt16") Then
                 If IsDBNull(dsrow(col.ColumnName)) Then
                      dsrow(col.ColumnName) = 0
                 End If
                 cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number
                 valor = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(CInt(dsrow(col.ColumnName)))
            Else
                If IsDBNull(dsrow(col.ColumnName)) Then
                    If col.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String") Then
                        dsrow(col.ColumnName) = ""
                    ElseIf col.DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime") Then
                        dsrow(col.ColumnName) = "01/01/1980"
                    ElseIf col.DataType.Name = "MySqlDateTime" Then
                        'no se le asigna ningun valor
                    Else
                        dsrow(col.ColumnName) = 0
                    End If
                End If
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String
                valor = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow(col.ColumnName).ToString)
            End If
            cell.CellValue = valor

            newRow.AppendChild(cell)
    Next

    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow)
Next
workbookPart.Workbook.Save()
End Using
```

Ahora bien, antes de guardar el archivo necesito crear el nuevo libro y en este libro agregar la tabla dinamica.

Estuve investigando acerca de la clase pivotTables de openxml pero no encontre mucha información y la mayoría esta en c# y solo tengo un par de semanas programando en vb.net así que no entiendo la mayoría de cosas que e encontrado

¿Alguien sabe como hacer eso? o me puede decir ¿donde puedo encontrar información mas detalla acerca de la clase pivotTables?